# Lambda over dataframe rows interacting with columns

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I am trying to apply this to my dataframe:
For each row:

- if row['colA']=='NONE' then row['colA']=row['colX']
- elif row['colA']!='NONE' & row['colB']=='NONE' then row['colB']=row['colX']

and so on. I am trying to do this with a lambda function so that:

```
dataframe.apply(lambda row: row['colA']=row['result'] if row['colA']=='NONE' else (row['colB']=row['result'] if row['colA']!='NONE' & row['colB']!='NONE'),axis=0)
```

But of course is not working. Is there a way to do something similar? If not I can work it out applying an iterative logic going column by column but I wondered if there was a faster way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

May be something like(*its better to always post some sample data to test*):

```
df=df.replace('NONE',np.nan)
df['colA']=df['colA'].fillna(df['colX'])
df['colB']=np.where(df['colA'].notnull()&df['colB'].isnull(),df['colB'].fillna(df['colX']),df['colB'])
#alternative for above line->
#df.loc[df.colA.notnull()&df.colB.isnull(),'colB']=df.loc[df.colA.notnull()&df.colB.isnull(),'colB'].fillna(df['colX'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If `NONE`are `string`s compare for boolean masks, `~` is for invert mask and set values by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'colA':['NONE', 'A', 'NONE', 'D'],
                   'colB':['NONE', 'B', 'C', 'NONE'],
                   'colX':['a','b','c','d']})
print (df)
   colA  colB colX
0  NONE  NONE    a
1     A     B    b
2  NONE     C    c
3     D  NONE    d

m1 = df['colA']=='NONE'
m2 = ~m1 & (df['colB']=='NONE')

df.loc[m1, 'colA'] = df.loc[m1, 'colX']
df.loc[m2, 'colB'] = df.loc[m2, 'colX'] 
print (df)
  colA  colB colX
0    a  NONE    a
1    A     B    b
2    c     C    c
3    D     d    d
```

And if `NONE` are `None` or `NaN` (missing value) change boolean masks:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'colA':[None, 'A',None, 'D'],
                   'colB':[None, 'B', 'C', None],
                   'colX':['a','b','c','d']})
print (df)
   colA  colB colX
0  None  None    a
1     A     B    b
2  None     C    c
3     D  None    d

m1 = df['colA'].isnull()
m2 = ~m1 & df['colB'].isnull()

df.loc[m1, 'colA'] = df.loc[m1, 'colX']
df.loc[m2, 'colB'] = df.loc[m2, 'colX'] 
print (df)
  colA  colB colX
0    a  None    a
1    A     B    b
2    c     C    c
3    D     d    d
```